# How can I implement B hopping?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement B-hopping but my code doesn't work. Is there a better way to implement it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public float airControl = 0.5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float bhopPower = 7.0f; // Adjust as needed for bhopping

    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Animator animator;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool canBhop = true; // Enable bhopping

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = characterController.isGrounded;
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput));
        move *= moveSpeed;

        // Calculate rotation
        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            // Ensure that the character is always facing the movement direction
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, targetAngle, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Determine if the character is walking left or right
        bool isWalkingLeft = horizontalInput < 0;
        bool isWalkingRight = horizontalInput > 0;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
                animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
                canBhop = true;
            }
            else if (move != Vector3.zero)
            {
                // Set the walking animation based on the movement direction
                animator.SetBool("Crawl", true);
                animator.SetBool("Idle", false);
                animator.SetBool("TurnLeft", isWalkingLeft);
                animator.SetBool("TurnRight", isWalkingRight);
            }
            else
            {
                animator.SetBool("Crawl", false);
                animator.SetBool("TurnLeft", false);
                animator.SetBool("TurnRight", false);
                animator.SetBool("Idle", true);
            }

            // Implement bhopping here
            if (canBhop && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                moveDirection.y += bhopPower;
                canBhop = false;
            }

            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                canBhop = true; // Enable bhopping when Space key is released
            }

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y -= gravity * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            // In the air - apply gravity
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            // Apply air control
            Vector3 airMove = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput));
            airMove *= moveSpeed * airControl;

            characterController.Move(airMove * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I am making a game where the player is a frog. I wanted to add b-hopping to the game but it doesn't seem to be working. I have been stuck on this issue for a couple days after hours of troubleshooting. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. What's actually going wrong? Can you explain more?